# lambda rdd.map gives: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Row' and 'float'

Tags: lambda, pyspark, rdd, data-science-experience

rdd.map gives: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Row' and 'float'

I create an rdd from a dataframe using:

```
temprdd = df.select('results').rdd
```

Then I want to do a calculation on all the objects in it (basically in my 'results' column which I now think is its own rdd):

```
sqrt(temprdd.map(lambda x : pow(x-mean,2)).sum())
```

But I'm getting:

> File "/usr/local/src/spark20master/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line
>   999, in 
>       return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)   File "", line 7, in
>    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Row' and
>   'float'

My mean is a float.  The value I'm expecting the x to be is a float; but is read as a Row I guess. What oh what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @mrsrinivas The mean is a variable set earlier. I tested it with a hardcoded '7' and then get: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Row' and 'int'. So I think the issue is the 'x' is not being resolved as I expect, not the mean. 'Row' doesn't make any sense, it should be a numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are selecting `results` column from `df` below

```
temprdd = df.select('results').rdd
```

Your lambda expression in `map` should be something like `x.results` instead of only `x` of Row type

```
temprdd.map(lambda x : pow(x.results - 7, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @mrsrinivas is helpful and I follow it. However it is missing one part which confused me.
The main issue code come from results that include `null` value. So for a table that include results column it code be selected using the following code:

```python
tempDF = df.select(df.results.cast('float').alias('results'))
tempDF.show(5)
```

The result will look like:

```python
+-------+
|results|
+-------+
|   null|
|   95.0|
|   93.0|
|   null|
|   87.0|
+-------+
```

So to not select the `null` values, you need to use the following code:

```python
tempDF_NoNull = tempDF.na.drop()
tempDF_NoNull.show(5)
```

And the result will be:

```python
+-------+
|results|
+-------+
|   95.0|
|   93.0|
|   87.0|
|   96.0|
|   82.0|
+-------+
```

Now to calculate the standard deviation for the results column, it could be calculated as following:

```python
std = sqrt(tempRDD.map(lambda x : pow(x.results-mean, 2)).sum()/count)
```